# Cannot launch AVD with api <= 17 with google apis

Tags: android, virtual-machine, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-manager

I accidentally deleted some files from android sdk directory (it was some files from system images). Then I started to get those errors when I run AVD with api <= 17 with google apis:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file!!
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined
```

Now I reinstalled android studio (version 2.1) and android sdk. But it did not fixed error.

What I've tried is to install arm eabi v7a system images, but in did not help.

What could I do?

Comment: Have you found answer?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm just using avd's without google apis - they works